# How can I find out if someone is actively using a Linux computer in Python or Java?

Tags: java, python

I want to write a program that ssh's into remote boxes and runs jobs there if the remote computer is not actively being used. I'll be logging in as clusterJobRunner@remoteBox, and the other user will be logged in as someLocalUser@remoteBox.

Is there a way to see if a remote user is actively using the box using either Python or Java?

Comment: Once the SSH connection is established, sounds like a job for `ps` and `grep`.

Comment: What if a user is running something in `screen`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the "actively used" part is the tricky part.

If it is sufficient to check whether or not another user is logged in, you can use the commands `w` and `who` and perhaps `last` and `lastlog`. All these commands several parameter which you can lookup in the manuals.

From Java / Python you can execute these commands and parse their output.

On the other hand: The tools `w` and `who` use the file `utmp` to get their information. A quick Google turned up nothing for Java but for Python I've found the library [pyutmp](http://software.clapper.org/pyutmp/) which you can use to read the `utmp` file directly without parsing the command output.

Whether the user logged in and went to lunch (possibly locking the screen) is a completely other story.

Answer (score 3):

If the aim is to avoid bothering someLocalUser, you could consider running your job on a lower priority. See the documentation for [nice](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_nice.htm).

Comment: +1 for suggesting `nice`, though it's not a panacea - the lower priority process might still hog I/O or memory while being very polite about CPU.

Comment: Yeah it's a pretty I/O & memory intensive process

Comment: @RussellBorogove Check also [`ionice`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice) from [util-linux](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/) package

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can execute the `users` Linux command using `Runtime.exec()`, grab the standard output and get it into a parsable `String`.  I don't think there are any OS-independent ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I second the answer by @Eero Aaltonen -- you should run your stuff under `nice`.  A Linux computer can run at 100% CPU busy, yet feel nice and fast for the user, if the extra tasks are all under `nice`; the scheduler will only run the `nice` tasks when the main user's tasks are idle.

But if you want to figure out if the machine is being used, I suggest you look into the `w` command.  Try `man w` at your prompt.  The `w` command prints the load average for the machine, and a list of users and how much time they have been using (a combined time that includes any background tasks they are running, plus a time for their main task).

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what "actively using" means to you. Which of the following defines "actively using":

1. A user is logged in
2. A user is actively engaging with the box, typing stuff into their ssh session.
3. A user is running a job

If #2 is what you are looking for, and users only log in using ssh, you could possibly hook into the sshd daemon and monitor whether it is receiving input from the ssh client.

For example if you attach strace to sshd of a logged in user, you can watch for reads from the ssh client. Here is an example that works for me:

```
$ for x in $(ps aux | grep sshd | grep "@pts" | sed -E 's/[^ ]+ +([0-9]*).*/\1/'); do {(sudo strace -p $x -eread 2>&1 | grep 'read(4' )&}; done
[1] 166396
[2] 166397
[3] 166399
[4] 166402
read(4, "\206\261\364\271\204\\\26S\3\"El\365W\352\35\375\242\205Qlu@$\2538\306\2777oW\230"..., 16384) = 36
read(4, "@s\2733d\355\17~\2550=\316`)3|^\340\f\252\242_\251\377d[l\221\210|z\37"..., 16384) = 36
read(4, "\5\214\261\25\322\222\242\221\313\314\4$\344\273\200\220a\233\345*\7\17\274\331\246\363f.\346\365\22\255"..., 16384) = 36
read(4, "\325\220<\0:\34^\235\346y\223\304\3061\212\203\373\371rD Rs\254oL*\260\22\234\372\27"..., 16384) = 36
read(4, "TXD\7\373~.\214\321\35\201\350\22\211\34J~m\\\270\364\243\267\261\207\323\224\314x\240i'"..., 16384) = 36
read(4, "\347\320\243\v/Z\213n\7\264\376\27\0340\30\364u!9\n\326\314)c\331\362\346\256\317E8\317"..., 16384) = 36
read(4, "\7\264\207\232\252xT\271\240Aq\210\21m\232l\306i\225\311\356\3
```

What you are seeing here is read calls on file descriptor 4 for all sshd forked processes for each user logged in using ssh. File descriptor 4 seems to be the one assigned to the socket connecting to the client (YMMV). Each line output means a user (or script) is sending something from the client to the server, and that seems to correspond to the user typing something into the shell.

You may be able to build on that.